# Getting Fatal Exception after showing "Custom Toast Message"

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to learn **Android** by following some online video tutorials.

I have seen one video for **How to create custom Toast Message.**

I followed same thing.But i am getting **Fatal Exception** after showing toast message(While closing ).

Exception is like below::

```
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:355)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:370)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:302)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-28 21:36:03.726: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

public void showCustomToast(View v)
{
    Toast toast = new Toast(this);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    LayoutInflater lin = getLayoutInflater();
    View appear = lin.inflate(R.layout.custom, 
                    (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1));
    toast.setView(appear);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

**custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ganesh" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ganesh"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Please provide solution before  -ve vote

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your toast with the context of the app:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(MainActivity.this);
```